# Why does the copy constructor for std::string appear to be faster than its move counterpart?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

I am trying to learn move semantics and I read that a move would likely be faster than a copy. However, I see quite the opposite for the following trivial code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    std::string a("Copy");
    std::string b = a;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    std::string a("Move");
    std::string b = std::move(a);
}
```

And here's the time it takes on my mac:

```
$ time ./copy.out
real    0m2.511s
user    0m2.481s
sys     0m0.011s


$ time ./move.out
real    0m3.993s
user    0m3.933s
sys     0m0.020s
```

Comment: Is that the entire code for the benchmark? Compiler flags?

Comment: I think your strings are too short to demonstrate real difference. Try with different length strings

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, I'm using clang with c++14 and optimization disabled (O0).

Comment: @Zaxter: benchmarks with disabled optimizations are meaningless.

Comment: Aaahhh... I see that... With (-O3) now the `move` version indeed performs better even for the same strings.

Comment: With commonly small buffer optimization for strings I would suspect no difference between move and copy constructor for short strings; for long strings the move constructor should outperform the copy, since the heap allocated memory can be moved then.

Comment: Your benchmark is somewhat dodgy btw, gcc for example manages to [eliminate the entire loop](https://godbolt.org/g/an3zKQ). You might want to have a look at sth like [this talk](https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk) for a quick overview of micro benchmarks.

Comment: I wonder if this code is suitable for measuring performance. How much of the time does construction of `a` take. Will the compiler skip construction of `a` in the second case? Will the compiler optimize everything away as no "output" is actually generated by the code?

Comment: In particular, clang generates *really* bad code at `-O0`, which is a huge pity since that's the only way clang can do debuginfo.

Comment: 90% of the time, `std::move` is a code smell...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As one of the comments suggests, most library implementations do a "short string optimization", SSO, wherein for a sufficiently short string (some specific length, for a given implementation), the entire string is stored in the body of the string object, on the stack. When your data is stored entirely on the stack, moving is the same as copying. All the implementations I know will SSO a 4 character string, so whether you move or copy it's pretty much well the same operation.

If you output the result of `sizeof(sring)`, choose a string larger than that, and use the same string for both cases. Also make sure optimizations are on.

This approach to micro-benchmarks is not so great. It's generally better to randomize data outside of the timing region, then perform the operation in a loop which is timed. Using the same constant data can often lead to crazy compiler optimizations that invalidate your results.